# Yii2: как получить поле с переводом?

Tags: php, yii2

Извините, если не понятно сформировал вопрос. Суть задачи: у меня есть мультиязычный сайт. В админ панели клиент заполняет данные на 3х языках. Например, новости. У них есть title. Я не создаю это поле в базе, а делаю его как `public $title`.

Дальше у меня есть метод, который получает перевод

```
public function t($row) {
/** тут по полю находится перевод **/
}
```

И вот я думал написать гетер, что бы можно было обращаться как к обычному полю

```
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->t('title');
}
```

Но Yii2 ругается. Как можно это обойти, что бы обращаться как к обычному полю?

Пример таблиц

```
news
id | status | created_at | updated_at
1  |   1    | 1281312312 | 1213311233

translations
id | table | lang | column | item_id | value
 1 | news  |  ru  | title  |    1    | Заголовок
 2 | news  |  en  | title  |    1    | Title
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, куда Вы сохраняете перевод поля `title`, если не в БД? Допустим у Вас есть значение этого поля на русском, английском и немецком языках - куда будут сохранены все эти три значения, чтобы в последствии их отобразить пользователю сайта в соответствии с выбранным им языком?

Comment: я сохраняю их в БД, просто не в эту таблицу. Есть общая таблица переводов, где хранится таблица, поле, id и значение

Comment: В таком случае приведите описание моделей этих таблиц. Исходя из этого уже и можно будет, что-то Вам посоветовать.

Comment: добавил в описание

Answer (score 0):

Не самая лучшая идея хранить именно так как у Вас, но жизнь бывает диктует свои условия...
Как бы сделал я. Создал базовую модель в которой описал метод `t` и все модели таблиц типа `news` унаследовал от нее.
Либо сделал `trait` и в каждую таблицу а-ля `news` его включал.
Первый вариант мне нравиться больше т.к мы будем много знать о таблице (например ее название) не передавая это как дополнительный параметр в функцию перевода.
Не дам 100% гарантии, что это все будет работать, но думаю при любом раскладе, хоть как-то я Вам помог :)

```php
class BaseModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Возвращает перевод указанного поля в зависимости от таблицы для которой он вызван и текущего языка
     * @param string $fieldName Имя поля в таблице для которого нужен перевод
     * @return string
     */
    public function t($fieldName = null ) {
        $result = '';
        if ( !is_null( $fieldname ) && trim( $fieldName ) != '' ) {
            //Имя таблицы - `news`
            $tableName = self::tableName();
            //текущий язык (учитывайте что он хранится в виде `en-US`, `ru-RU` и т.д
            //а у Вас по условиям задачи как `en`, 'ru'
            $lang = \Yii::$app->language;
            $model = Translations::findOne(['table' => $tableName, 'lang' => $lang, 'column' => $fieldName]);
            if ( !is_null( $model ) ) {
                $result = $model->value;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Ну и собственно сам класс новостей

```php
class News extends BaseModel {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'news';
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Возвращает перевод для поля `title` в зависимости от текущего языка
     * хотя я бы напрямую вызывал сразу ->t()
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->t('title');
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. у меня используется как раз второй вариант - трейт. но мой вопрос немного не в том.  если взять ваш код, как мне использовать поле title в ActiveForm?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос :) Объявите в модели внутреннюю переменную, опишите ее в `rules` - выводите на форме и получайте после сабмита ее значение. Все это есть на сайте `Yii` в документации и примерах.

Comment: и вот мы и вернулись к моему вопросу) если вы в своем коде объявите переменную public $title, то вы не сможете использовать метод getTitle(), а это значит, что при обращении $model->title вы не получите перевод. так что это один и тот же вопрос)

Comment: Боюсь Вы невнимательно читали документацию `Yii2` особенно в части `magic`-методов у моделей. Имя переменной тут никакой роли не играет, назовите ее - `$_title`.

Comment: я читал и знаю это. суть вопроса: может ли быть и public $title и getTitle? например, в Laravel можно создать getTitleAttr() и обращаться к нему ->title

Comment: @Diefair видимо читали невнимательно :)
`
/**
 * @property string $title 
*/
class News extends BaseModel {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'news';
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Возвращает перевод для поля `title` в зависимости от текущего языка
     * хотя я бы напрямую вызывал сразу ->t()
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->t('title');
    }
}
`
Обращение к `( new News())->title` - вызовет функцию `getTitle()`